# How to collect logs such as RTT and Avg RTT on Mininet?

Tags: python-3.x, sdn, mininet, openflow

Can anybody please guide me on how we can get logs for RTT and Avg RTT on Mininet while using custom topology code provided in examples. Hoping for your response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure RTT You may refer to this research [paper](http://www.deepness-lab.org/pubs/infocom2016_grami.pdf)
.
The implementation is [here](https://github.com/alonatari1/GRAMI) for the above paper. Though I could find another [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6324/43285f2558c33d9223bf7b17a2e811e17f69.pdf), but i think this one would not give quite an accurate result. (Clock synchronization problems). Anyways You can have a look for motivation.